# iOS - Adaptive layout (Size classes) Fetch Data as early as possible, one time and place a UIView in viewcontrollers views center

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, size-classes, adaptive-layout

Im using Auto layout with Size classes enabled.
I want to fetch data as soon as possible and it works fine doing this in:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchData()
}
```

The problem is that the frame is not yet calculated and gives a frame of i.e 600x600 which is the canvas size in storyboard. This means that if I want to place a custom loader in the center by using:

```
self.loader.center = self.view.center
```

This will make the loader be place someplace far away from the center. 
I can fix the loader placement by calling fetchData in:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    fetchData()
}
```

But this makes it fetch more than only one time. 
So my question is: When should I fetchData(), I want it to happen as early as possible. Only one time, and I want to loader to be centered.

Thanks

Edit: Disabling Auto Layout or Size classes is not an option.

Comment: Simply put `self.loader.center = self.view.center` into `viewWillAppear()` and leave `fetchData()` in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: hmm I mean what if fetchData would be done before viewWillAppear() ? The loader removeFromSuperview() is at the end of fetchData @krumelur

Comment: set the loader nil and check in viewWillAppear()?

Answer (score 0):

Use this,
    self.loader.center =    CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2);

SWIFT:
self.loader.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/2)

or you can try fetching your data from viewWillLayoutSubviews method

Comment: Fetching data in viewWilllayoutSubviews is not a good solution since that method can be called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: 
Use:

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
```

to force the view to draw itself and setup the constraints.